# as3 Why do I feel like I am fighting Flash Develop (on mac)?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5.5

I am creating Web, Android, and IOS games and applications in Flash Pro CS 5.5

I really like this program, and I use it for laying this out, creating movieclips, storing all the assets in a library, publishing, and even compiling and testing.

The problem is that the code editor is, eh, bad. I had downloaded Flash Develop, but I don't think I am using it correctly (the way it wants me to use it). It wants me to republish a swc every time I make a change. That is simply not pracical with the way that I work. There is too much going on in Flash Develop, and I get overwhelmed.

Really, the only thing I like about Flash Develop is that putting the cursor next to a curly brace tells you where the other one is (most of my errors have to do with those cursed curly braces).

I tried to start a new Flash Develop project, and ended up getting mad going back to the old method.

However, now every letter of the file is underlined in red. I can't even open this file anymore in Flah Develop!
If anyone can recommend a nice MAC cas3 code editor that would be fantastic.

Comment: Have you tried out FDT Free?  Flash Develop is great in Windows, but Mac's version has way to go.

Comment: As prototypical mentioned, Flash Develop is based around the coding of Flash projects, and thus it is better fitted to projects that rely heavily on code. Its function is to simplify and ease the process of writing and organising the code, and if your project is not heavily code based, it can be more of a hindrance than a help. It would be better to use a simple code editor with syntax colouring and text editing functions to edit your code. Something like TextWrangler (which I've read is a good Mac alternative for Notepad++) should suffice.

Comment: For many years (not any longer, for various reasons, mainly moving to other workplace, other team) I used Flash Pro CS in conjunction with TextMate and the ActionScript 3 bundle for TextMate. I did the scripting (main part of my work) in TextMate and handled resources and compiled the swf using Flash Pro CS, switching between the two constantly during my work day. Sounds to me that something like that could be suitable for you, but perhaps with Sublime instead of TextMate these days.

Answer (score 0):

You feel like you are fighting Flash Develop because you don't understand how to use it. You likely have not advanced your knowledge of AS3/Programming enough to actually appreciate what it does.

Your goal should be to learn how to use it correctly. There are numerous advantages to using Flash Develop as opposed to the IDE. If you are constantly modifying your content and have less of a need for the coding functionality that Flash Develop brings to the table, then the Flash IDE might be best for you.

Check out these links and you'll see how much more efficient you can become in a proper coding IDE :

http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=Features:Generation

http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=Shortcuts

Comment: The thing is that I want to compile and publish from the IDE. How can I set up Flash Develop so that I can write code easily without setting up a project?

Comment: Flash Develop has project templates for compiling via Flash IDE and just doing your coding in Flash Develop. Not having a project takes away some of the functionality that makes Flash Develop useful. You can however just open and edit the .as files in Flash Develop and compile from the IDE. But if you aren't up to the task of being more efficient, stick with the Flash IDE. Your mindset is similar to "I want to work with Flash IDE, but I don't want to take the time to learn how to use it".